# Using Point-Density-Function to model holes in FreeCAD Model

Tags: python, freecad

I am designing a Part for an Experiment, which is basically a sheet of some sort with holes cut into it.

The holes need to be spaced out according to some measurements, where the amount of holes in the middle needs to be larger than the holes along the outside, similar to the diagramm bellow.

I read up on the Python integration for FreeCAD, but I'm a little overwhelmed with the documentation and frankly don't know where to start.

[image]

How to I translate a point density simulation like this as holes-to-be-drilled on a part?

I would imagine something along the lines of extracting the coordinates of each point and then translating those onto the FreeCAD Model.

Thank you,
Toni